# Not seeing my log messages - Django/Apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/Users/user/djangoLogs/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I've added the following to my views.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

However, I'm not seeing any of my log messages in the debug.log. I do see some Django logs/error messages so it seems like the native Django logging is working.

Here's an example of a log message that I'm expecting to see:

```
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    logger.debug("get_thumbnails call failed: ", e)
```

httpd.conf

```
#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel debug
```

mod-wsgi version is 4.6.4
Django version is 2.1

Comment: Django version?

Comment: The Django version is 2.1 and mod_wsgi version is 4.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django comes with an [in-built logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/). Use that to produce the logs.

**Example**:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
        'your_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/logs'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'your_logger': {
            'handlers': ['your_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        }
    },
}
```

**EDIT**:

Updated the above piece of code to include a custom logger named `your_logger` which you can use from your view to write to.

**view**:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('your_logger')
```

Comment: Will the filename be the apache error log? `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: @brewcrazy That totally depends on you.

Comment: With that configuration (filename /var/log/django/debug.log I get `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'`

Comment: Probably, it cant reach the file path you may have given to it. Create the file wherever you want, put its path, update file's permissions so that logger can write to it.

Comment: The file path is in my home directory with the following permissions (as a test): `drwxrwxrwx`. Still getting the same error

Comment: I've got django logging to the file now. However, my log message is still not showing up in that log file. I am seeing a Django log in the file.